# Tablesorter sort order not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

My tablesorter custom parser sort order is not working properly and it doesn't seem like I'm doing anything wrong. Can anyone shed some light here?

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "sample",
  is: function (s) {
    return false;
  }, 
  format: function (s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replace(/blood/,1).replace(/RnD/,2).replace(/unassigned/,3)
  }, 
  type: "numeric"  
});
```

and to implement the sort

```
$("#revSummaryTb").tablesorter({
  sortList: [[3,0]],
  headers: {
    0: { sorter:'text'},
    1: { sorter:'digit'},
    2: { sorter:'text'},
    3: { sorter:'sample'}
  }
});
```

with column 3 being the column of interest. However, this ends up sorting my columns totally wrong with going from one to the other and then back (aka no real sort). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If the table cells contain more text than just "blood", "RnD" and "unassigned" then the plugin is attempting to sort the remaining text as a numeric value. If you provide an example of the column content, it would be easier to troubleshoot the exact problem.

Comment: the content was "sample_blood", "sample_RnD", "sample_unassigned". It can only be one of those 3.

Comment: Then the parser is returning "sample_1", "sample_2" and "sample_3" and assuming it's numeric. Switch the parser type to "text" and it will start working.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I used "Rnd", "blood", and "unassigned" for simplicity here. The text I am searching for in the parser will match the exact text of the values in the cells (not just a portion of that value)

Comment: Set up a demo please

Comment: My original post is a demo! My original post has the issue as described with those replace values being the full values in the cells.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the parser type to "text":

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
  id: "sample",
  is: function (s) {
    return false;
  },
  format: function (s) {
    return s.toLowerCase().replace(/blood/,1).replace(/RnD/,2).replace(/unassigned/,3);
  },
  type: "text"
});
```

Comment: Why would I want to sort numbers as text

Comment: In this case, the replace method will return "sample_1", "sample_2" and "sample_3" which are not numeric values. When the numeric parser is set, it will attempt to parse the result into a numeric value, fail and fall back to using text... And use the numeric sorting algorithm when attempting to sort the column. When the numeric sorting algorithm encounters text, it will not optimally sort the values.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I used "Rnd", "blood", and "unassigned" for simplicity here. The text I am searching for in the parser will match the exact text of the values in the cells (not just a portion of that value). Therefore the replace method will return "1", "2", and "3".